# NodeJS creating file in another drive (windows)

Tags: node.js

I'm running my NodeJS service on drive D:\

I want my service to create a log file in another drive (C:) and write logs into it.

Is it possible?

Comment: What did you try? Probably using the absolute PATH of the file would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Writing/creating files in NodeJS is not limited to the app-folder or drive. Assuming you have write-permissions to the (already existing) target directory, you can simply use the `writeFile` method from the `fs`-module:

```
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  try {
    const path = 'c:\\Temp\\Test.txt';
    const data = 'Some data!';
    await fs.promises.writeFile(path, data);
    console.log('successful write to ' + path);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('write error:  ' + error.message);
  }
})();
```