# NodeJS saving file to another drive

Tags: node.js, windows

I am running NodeJS services on drive 'D:'
But I want to save the uploaded file to drive 'E:' in the server.
Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS creating file in another drive (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62277481/nodejs-creating-file-in-another-drive-windows)

Comment: I have tried this, but it aint working.

Comment: Then maybe you should update your question and include the specific error that you are encountering. How do you expect people to help you with your issue if you don't describe what is going wrong concretely? You asked if something was possible. It is. If it's not working, you need to give more information. Can't be that hard, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can save your file whenever you want but need appropriate access permission. Use `fs` for saving your files. Please see the official document https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

```
const data = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from('Hello Node.js'));
fs.writeFile('message.txt', data, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```